# JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657) In Return statement

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to build a Tic Tac Toe app that will let me choose 3x3, 4x4 and 5x5 grid and currently i'm stuck on 3x3 grid and I'm getting 'JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)'

```
const newGameState = {
    squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    xIsNext: true,
  }

  class Game3x3 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = newGameState
    }
  
    whoseTurn() {
      return this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O'
    }
  
    onNewGame() {
      this.setState(newGameState)
    }
  
    onMove(i) {
      let newSquares = this.state.squares.slice()
      const turn = this.whoseTurn()
      if (this.state.squares[i] || winner(this.state.squares)) return null
      newSquares[i] = turn
      this.setState({
        squares: newSquares,
        xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
      })
    }

  
    render() {
      const style = {
        backgroundColor: 'beige',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
      }
  // this is the return statement that give me an error v
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={style}>
          <Board squares={this.state.squares} onMove={(i) => this.onMove(i)} />
          <Status turn={this.whoseTurn()} winner={winner(this.state.squares)} onNewGame={() => this.onNewGame()} />
        </SafeAreaView>
      )



    }
```

I tried adding another view element but it didn't work. I will be gratefull to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a appears that I didn't have to use that return statement.